# How to add 2 records to database from a single array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 8 with the Excel package. I have an array from a csv import  as:

> array("Mr", "Tom", "Staff", "and", "Mr", "John", "Doe")

In my **model function** below, I am struggling to add 2 separate records for these two without duplicating code.
In the code above, all I do is sort the csv data into their correct fields as title, firstName etc. It's all sorted into an array called **name** which is inside the object **homeowner** So:

- title = Mr
- firstName = Tom
- lastName = Staff
- title2 = Mr
- firstName2 = John
- lastName2 = Doe

  ```
   public function model(array $row)
   {
       if (count($row) == 3) {
           $homeowner = new ThreeWordName($row);
       }elseif (count($row) == 7) {
           $homeowner = new SevenWordName($row);
       }

       $sorter = new CsvNameSorter;
       $sorter->sort($homeowner);

       return new temp_csv_data([
           'title'         => $homeowner->name['title'],
           'firstName'     => $homeowner->name['firstName'],
           'lastName'      => $homeowner->name['lastName'],
           'title'         => $homeowner->name['title2'],
           'firstName'     => $homeowner->name['firstName2'],
           'lastName'      => $homeowner->name['lastName2'],
       ]);
   }
  ```

Comment: This can be fixed, but what do you want to be created into two rows? do you want to duplicate tempCsvData or?

Comment: @mrhn i have a database with 3 columns, title firstname and lastname. I want to add each nane as a new record.

Comment: @Constantin interesting but I am not able to see how this actually helps. I read through all 3 links but stil confused. Mainly on how I can insert the 2 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As importing to model in `Laravel Excel`, is about mapping one row to a model, if you use importing to model.

Instead you could import to a collection and create your logic.

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if (count($row) == 3) {
            $homeowner = new ThreeWordName($row);
        }elseif (count($row) == 7) {
            $homeowner = new SevenWordName($row);
        }

        $sorter = new CsvNameSorter;
        $sorter->sort($homeowner);

        TempCsvData::create([
            'title' => $homeowner->name['title'],
            'firstName' => $homeowner->name['firstName'],
            'lastName' => $homeowner->name['lastName'],
        ]);

        TempCsvData::create([
            'title' => $homeowner->name['title2'],
            'firstName' => $homeowner->name['firstName2'],
            'lastName' => $homeowner->name['lastName2'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

As a note, class naming is pascal cased.

Comment: Does this go against the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle?

Comment: Firstly i think compared to the question this should not be your focus to focus on higher design principles. Also ::create calls in Laravel is very repetetive, but that is a tradeoff you have for how their design is made. But if it's a problem you can just create a helper function that can fix it for you, i to be honest don't see the big deal. This for me was more to solve, how to actually create the two models than design.